# Direct Download a GCS object via a site

Tags: pdf, download, google-cloud-storage

thanks for reading this.

I've made **PDF's available for instant download** via a site, **using buckets with uniform AllUsers access**. When customers visited the site, they clicked on the button and downloaded the GCS object, i.e. the menu from the restaurant.

Apparently, that doesn't work like that anymore. When I recently added a bucket with an updated menu, **now**, when clicking on the button on the site, **the customer is directed to the GCS User Interface**. You can imagine the customer clicking away in seconds and ordering in another take-away.

So now, the menu is no longer downloadable, even if I did the exact same thing as with the previous versions.

Can someone tell me what changed or how to fix this?
Would be awesome.

Kind regards,
Erik

Comment: Google Cloud Storage supports public access. Edit your question and show how you have configured bucket access.

Comment: Thank you. I will do so if the other answer doesn't do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you have set your bucket public, you should have something like that in your console

[image]

There are several things to note here

- At the bottom, the permissions section tell me `Public to internet`. That confirm my openness to download over internet
- You have 2 URLs:

  - Public URL: this one to use in your code
  - Authenticated URL: which required an authentication to reach it

The differences of 2 last URL are subtil and not obvious at the first glance! Public is `storage.googleapis.com`, authenticated is `storage.cloud.google.com`. Pick the googleapis.com one.

Comment: Hi there, I tried what you did, but it is still the same.

Comment: Is your bucket in uniform IAM permission or not?

Comment: made a small website with screenshots

Comment: Yes, I think it is in uniform IAM, but will check

Comment: I typed the 2 public URLs in my browser and I successfully download the files. They are publicly accessible. Does the issue happen only from your website? Does the issue come from there?

Comment: Maybe. I'll add the same button to the previously made website (downloadfromgcs.carrd.co) like on the website of the restaurant (vivobrugge.be). Could you check that site as well? Thank you. (or should I say Merci :)   )

Comment: When entering this address as link for the button: https://storage.googleapis.com/vivoprijslijst/Black%20and%20Cream%20Modern%20Pizza%20Catering%20Trifold%20Brochure%20(30).pdf  it automatically makes it https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/_details/vivokaart/Black%20and%20Cream%20Modern%20Pizza%20Catering%20Trifold%20Brochure%20%2830%29pdf.pdf

Comment: That's very strange. Do you have a corporate firewall or network element that can change stuff? Did you try with your smartphone for example?

Comment: Hi Guillaume, I found it. When defining the bucket, there was this item to be unchecked called 'Enforce public access prevention on this bucket' that I didn't uncheck. It was something I overlooked and previously wasn't there in my memory. Thanks for helping with the search. Much appreciated.